# В каком числе поставить должность?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Назначить на должность аудиторов или Назначить на должности аудиторов или Назначить на должности аудитора или Назначить на должность аудитора (им. в виду две кандидатуры)

Comment: Две кандидатуры (два претендента), а вакансий сколько?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Назначить на должности аудиторов...**

Два аудитора назначаются на две должности (два служебных места),  также будут изданы два приказа об их назначении.

**ДОЛЖНОСТЬ,** Служебное положение, **место** и связанные с ним служебные обязанности.  Штатная д.

Пример:

... пришлось бы **назначить на должности командиров батарей** малоопытных и совершенно неподготовленных обер-офицеров; [Е. З. Барсуков. Русская артиллерия в мировую войну (1938)]